# determining how many columns are returned by a SProc

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

Morning, im trying to store the results of any SProc call, from SQL Server2008, in an object[], as i have heard that constructing a datatable is a bit wasteful especially when some of the SProc's will return only 3 fields. The example i found explicitly states how many columns there are:

[MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getvalues.aspx)

but i need a way to be able to determine this as each SProc will return a different number.

If this is possible i would appreciate some pointers.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [SqlDataReader.FieldCount Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.fieldcount). In the pair with [SqlDataReader.GetName Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getname) you could get the returned column names, if you need it.

Comment: thats what i was looking for, thank you very much! Ill accept this as the answer in 7mins.